# How can I switch option (alt) and command (windows) keys for Windows 7 in Boot Camp?

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows

Installed Windows 7 via [Bootcamp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) for some work-related projects. I've also installed the Apple Bootcamp drivers from the OS X install disk and updated to the latest version. It mapped all my keys just fine, but I was surprised it does not offer an option to switch the mappings of <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> keys; ie. <kbd>Alt</kbd> is left of <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> key is left of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

The current way directly maps to the physical keyboard layout, but not to the way people are used to working: e.g. OS X's <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for window switching is equivelant to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> not <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I keep hitting the wrong keys because of muscle memory. :)

Is there a built-in way to remap <kbd>Windows</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys? If not, what 3rd party app is the best way to do this?

Comment: This seems like a Windows question - maybe it should be migrated to Super User?

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue.  Resolved it using Sharp Keys (free).

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

Comment: Didn't work for me (Windows 7 64bit)

Comment: Also did not work for me on W7 64 bit. Alt is not available to be remapped.

Comment: It works for me with Windows 10 64bit, make sure you have to logoff and login again after applying the configuration (Sharp Keys has told you to logoff! ) Besides, for the Alt button, although it is not detected by the "Type Key", you can still select if manually from the menu, I am swapping Alt and Command button and it works on my MBA 2012.

Answer (score 10):

I've been using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for about a year on Win7 Ultimate x64. Works great.

In addition to swapping the left Command and Option keys, I've remapped the right Command to forward delete, and right Option to "AppsKey" (aka, context menu) which helps in Visual Studio and other apps.

If you want function keys to work as, well, function keys (without having to hold down Fn), you can set that in the Bootcamp application via the system tray icon.

Here's a script just for swapping left Option (alt) and Command (Windows):

```
RAlt::AppsKey ; right-Option to context menu
RWin::Del ; right command to forward delete
LWin::LAlt ; left command to alt
LAlt::LWin ; left alt to command (windows key)
```

You may also consider remapping Caps Lock if you need an additional key since, really, how often do any of us use Caps Lock?

Comment: Nice, especially since I already use AutoHotkey for a lot of other stuff, but bothersome because I switch between a "real" Windows keyboard and my Apple keyboard.

Comment: @Jan I feel your pain. Having to start and stop AutoHotkey when docking is annoying. At least there's the system try icon.

Comment: No, I mean I have a general AutoHotkey script that I'd have to have two versions of, or figure out if there's some identifier that AutoHotkey can use for an 'if' section. Gotta love AHK though.

Comment: @Jan Ahhh... that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script file for the Apple keyboard with F hotkeys and CMD hotkeys too.
https://github.com/stroebjo/autohotkey-windows-mac-keyboard

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like Sharp Keys because it requires a restart to swap mappings. Other AutoHotKey scripts here had too much extra stuff for my needs. [This AutoHotKey script](https://gist.github.com/Jerph/0b3635a1226bb27122f75c33306c268e) is only the win key swap, plus a hotkey to turn it off (ctrl+F6) if you also occasionally use a Windows keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a trick that you can remap some less used keys to keys you prefer. E.g. I map right CMD to DEL and right ALT to menu('application'), using Sharpkeys